# Creating static new data columns on the left side using query and arrayformula Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

Here is the sheet [Copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XMjSkU19EaB7iCcybCvNl47hJuLuvKjhf2ZlfSqQuQ4/copy) OR [View](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XMjSkU19EaB7iCcybCvNl47hJuLuvKjhf2ZlfSqQuQ4/edit?usp=sharing)

I have a table as shown

[image]

I need to display the items with price > 10 and they must be always prefixed with Timestamp and User along with query results as shown

[image]

I have tried to static values to query result using the below formula but I have not succeeded

```
=Arrayformula({{{"05-16-2021","James"}}&{query(A3:Z10,"Select * where F>10")}})
```

Comment: not quite clear how you want to specify the **timeshtamp** and **user name** - but if the question is about adding columns of data in the query - you can try this formula `=query(A2:F7,"select '05-16-2021','James',A,B,C,D,E,F where F>10 label '05-16-2021''Timeshtamp','James''User' ")`

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergey, Why dont you post this as an answer. It works great

Answer (score -1):

You can try this formula

```
=query(A2:F7,"select '05-16-2021','James',A,B,C,D,E,F where F>10 label '05-16-2021''Timeshtamp','James''User' ")
```

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: @jonathan then it's probably outdated. Seemed to have worked at the posted date, as comments on the question suggests.